# Capacitor Browser issue with Redirect

Tags: ionic-framework, redirect, browser, capacitor, inappbrowser

The Capacitor Browser is having issues with web redirects - with different behaviors in iOS and Android.  I think this is a very buggy plugin, but maybe I'm missing something...

My Ionic app uses the Capacitor Browser plugin to present a Federation Login page.  There is an "authentication URL" returned upon successful SSO login - or if the user is already logged in then there is an immediate "authentication URL" redirect.

Here's what I am seeing...

**iOS**: for a first time login, the web redirect works and deep links back into my app -- no problem here.  However, if SSO is active, then there is an immediate redirect which the Browser ignores.  I can see the URL change, and it works if I open it in a separate mobile web browser.

**Android**: for a first time login, the web redirect is ignored and the user is left stuck in the browser.  Again, if I copy the URL to a separate web browser then it deep links back into the app.

Has anyone done this successfully or have any workarounds?  I've tried the "Cordova" and "Awesome" InAppBrowser versions of this plugin, and they don't redirect at all (although they have a bit more control over closing the browser, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a problem like this on Android lately,
The in app redirection was down on Android 12, users where locked on a white screen where we normally get the token in the url and redirect in app.

In my case it was related to this :
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations?authuser=2

The chrome browser was trying to check this file to verify the hash of the app to perform the redirection but it was unavailable due to internal network configuration, so it was locked.
This check seems to append on Android 12 only, and needed a re-install of the app on users devices (cache on in app browser ?).

Hope this can help.
(Ionic 6 Capacitor)

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, I really appreciate your answer and it was good to finally see someone else experience this issue and "not just me".  Your answer makes sense and I will try that -- thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem. when deep linking trying to open the redirect URL within the app, its locked on a white screen. I have tried to clear the browser cache and change default browser and reinstalled the app but none of these have worked!